# Plugin source code errors after reinstallation

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

So I have just installed the latest eclipse version (4.6.3) on my laptop which had 4.6.2 running before.

The problem is that all my eclipse plugin projects are now full of errors because it somehow can't resolve various bundles (`swt`, `osgi`, `eclipse.core`, `eclipse.ui`, etc).

Furthermore I have noticed that the target platform the `PDE` sets up as default (which is the running platform) complains that it can't find the respecive plugins either.

I don't know if these two issues are connected but it seems to me that eclipse can't find it's own plugins which would be very weird...

Does someone has an idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Try clicking Edit on the Target Platform preferences to make sure it is finding the current code. Generally it gives more control to use a separate target platform - I usually use one of the minimal Eclipse downloads from the [Eclipse Projects site](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/)

Comment: What do you mean with `finding the current code`?

Comment: Okay I uninstalled the new eclipse version and then installed a 4.6.1 and the errors in the plugins sources are gone. However the target platform had the same errors but creating a new one with the default settings from the running one seemed to do the job... I guess the new eclipse version is just pretty buggy

Comment: You might retry that with 4.6.3.